# Use connectionstring from web.config in source code file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this might be a very basic question, but maybe thats why I'm having problems finding the answer. Right now I'm creating database connections in my source files by doing something like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=...Password=...);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table;"), con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But this means that if I choose to change databases it will be a major pain. Do you guys know how to use the connection string from a web.config file instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you closing / disposing your connections / commands / readers?  If you're not using the 'using' keyword, start!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString);
```

Make sure that your website has a reference to System.Configuration or it won't work.

The documentation can be found as [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx), with code sample

Comment: How about for OLEDB connection?

Comment: You should be able to find that info at connection strings.com.

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
var conString = System.Configuration.
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"];
string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
```

Comment: +1: Note that the OP may have to manually add the System.Configuration reference to his project.

Answer (score 5):

In your app.config (or web.config):

```
<configuration>
       <connectionStrings>
           <add name="MainConnectString" connectionString="yourConnectionString" providerName="providerName" />
       </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And in code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectString"];
```

Answer (score 2):

along with StackOverflowException's response, make sure to add **using System.Configuration;** to your code behind page

Answer (score 1):

You can use EnterpriseLibrary.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
```

Then you create a method to get connection string:

```
 public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        Database YourData = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("someconnectionname");
        return YourData .ConnectionString;
    }
```

In your web.config you will have following:

```
 <connectionStrings>   
   <add name="someconnectionname" connectionstring=..... />
 </connectionString>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get "cannot implicitly convert type 'system.configuration.connectionstringsettings' to 'string'", do:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectString"].ConnectionString;
```